# How to get object from a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to get object in a list. I have following code

```
List<Product> productList = GetList();

var product = (from p in productList 
                   where p.Id == "xyz"
                   select new Product()
                       {
                           Id = p.Id,
                           -,
                           -
                       });

foreach ( var p in product)
{
    //some code
}
```

I need to get object directly into var product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the more sensible "method"-syntax instead of the query syntax.

```
var product = productList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == "xyz");
```

Edit: There's a couple of different methods you can use to get the element you're after.

`.SingleOrDefault()` will try to find the item you're looking for, returning null (default) if there is no object matching your expression.

`.Single()` will do the same thing, except it will throw an exception if the object wasn't found.

`.FirstOrDefault()` will get a list of objects matching your expression, and retrieve the first one. If there's several objects with Id `xyz`, both `.Single()` and `.SingleOrDefault()` will throw an exception.

`.First()` works like `.FirstOrDefault()` but similarly to `.Single()` will throw an exception if you didn't find what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Product> productList = GetList();

var product = (from p in productList 
                   where p.Id == "xyz"
                   select new Product()
                       {
                           Id = p.Id,
                           -,
                           -
                       }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either `.SingleOrDefault()` or `.Single()`.

```
var product = (from p in productList 
                   where p.Id == "xyz"
                   select new Product()
                       {
                           Id = p.Id,
                           -,
                           -
                       }).Single();
```

If `productList` is already a list of `Product`, then don't rebuild a new instance of the `Product` object using `select new`.

You could simply do:

```
var product = productList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == ...);
```